# Excel not accepting a number

Tags: excel-2013

In a spreadsheet, I have a column formatted as number, no decimal places.
I enter 1607809547722210
Then below that I try to enter 1607809547722211, press enter, and the value reverts to 1607809547722210
It seems to do this for anything above that number

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Excel is representing your number as a double, and 15-16 digits is the most precision a double can have.